# Using multiple flags with cargo

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I want to run tests with release optimisations using 1 test thread.

I can do these individually:

```
cargo test -- --test-threads=1
cargo test --release
```

How would I put these together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use both in a single command like this:

```
cargo test --release -- --test-threads=1
```

---

**How Cargo interprets these arguments ?**

According to test subcommand's synopsis in [reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-test.html) :

> `cargo test [OPTIONS] [TESTNAME] [-- TEST-OPTIONS]`

Cargo interprets  input as :

- Arguments before separator (`--`) will be used as an **option** for `test` subcommand. In your case `cargo test` accepts profile parameter as an **option** since it builds the project. Available options can be found under [this title](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-test.html#cargo_test_options), or by running `cargo test --help`.
- Arguments after the separator will be passed to the test binaries. In Rust project, Cargo uses `rustc`'s [libtest](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/tree/master/src/libtest) to run unit tests. In your case `--test-threads=1` will be an argument for `libtest`.

*This interpretation might not be valid for other subcommands, it is best to check other cargo commands from [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/index.html). Checking **synopsis** section will give you a huge hint about capabilities of `cargo`'s subcommands.*

---

**See also**:

- Since arguments after the dash will be sent to the `rustc's` `libtest` you can see available options for testing by: `cargo test -- --help`.
- Profile options can be found under [this title](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-test.html#cargo_test_profiles)